# How authenticate a user in active directory that have to change his password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to login an account in Active Directory with have to change this password (pwdlastset = '0'). The problem I've found is that when this propertie of the entity is enabled, the ldap method can not authenticate with old password. I'am doing the connection with a ruby client and I need to authenticate the user before send the replace instruction to de unicodePwd to avoid security problems. How can I check old password when I have pwdlastset enabled?

A bit of pseudocode:

```
ldap_con.new(ldap_params)
auth = ldap_con.auth(login, old_pass) # Fail when pwdlastset eql 0
ldap_con.modify(:dn => dn, :operations => [:replace, "unicodePwd", new_pass]) if auth
```

If I change the pass without authenticate, someone can change the pass of an account without old credentials.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [pwdLastSet to "-1"](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Pwd-Last-Set%20attribute#section-Pwd-Last-Set+attribute-ModificationsToPwdLastSetAttribute) and then set the password for the user.
As I recall, these need to be done in two LDAP operations.

-jim

Comment: Two operations are needed when there are not an Admin user. If is the own user who want to change this password need "delete" and "add" operations. About question, only Admin user can edit an user because own user can not do it with pwdlastset params. There are another solution?